# Lazy loading vs individually loading each property for foreign keys

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

Since I am using Entity Framework 6 Database First and my database has all of its relationships setup, my EDMX auto generates navigation properties for me whether they are object lists or individual objects. This way I can lazy load using .Include(x => x.NavProperty).

How would I handle something such as the following using lazy loading that was previously done in a stored procedure that would return a list of OrderDetailDto which has a string property called MaterialDescription?

```
SELECT od.*, IIF(m.Description is null, od.Description, m.description) as MaterialDescription
FROM OrderDetail od
LEFT OUTER JOIN Material m ON od.MaterialId = m.Id
```

I am really trying to avoid doing this but I might end up ignoring all of the build in navigation properties and create a Dto for each entity and strictly add the properties I want bound to it. Then do selects like the following:

```
using (var context = new AppContext())
      {
        var odList = (from od in context.MaterialPODetails
                       join m in context.Materials on od.MaterialId equals m.Id into gj
                       from m in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select OrderDetailDto
                       {
                           Id = od.Id,
                           MaterialPOId = od.MaterialPOId,
                           MaterialId = od.MaterialId,
                           Description = od.Description,
                           Unit = od.Unit,
                           Quantity = od.Quantity,
                           UnitPrice = od.UnitPrice,
                           Archived = od.Archived,
                           DateCreated = od.DateCreated,
                           CreatedBy = od.CreatedBy,
                           DateModified = od.DateModified,
                           ModifiedBy = od.ModifiedBy,

                           // navigation properties
                           MaterialDescription = (m == null ? obj.Description : m.Description)
                       }).ToList();
        return odList;
            }
      }
```

Please give me any advice possible on how to avoid. I want to avoid creating Dtos and simply use the Auto Generated EF classes with the virtual properties but it seems that there is limitations and performance differences. I won't be able to do the If statement that I want to do with the left outer join.

I don't know if this is proper terminology but I believe what I want is to still use Flattened objects but not have to create Dtos.